# Rails Load Class Changes without restarting the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails setup that is something like this.

app/service/TestService.rb

```
class TestService

  def self.doSomething
    return 'Hello World!'
  end

end
```

I am using this file in the controller.

```
require 'TestService'

class IndexController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @message = TestService.doSomething
  end

end
```

I also added this in application.rb inside the config folder, so that rails autoload classes in service folder.

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/service)
```

But the application doesn't seem to pick up updates to TestService class. How can I fix this, so that changes in TestService class show up without restarting the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `require` when attempting to load a file containing a reloadable constant.

Normally, you will not need to do anything special to be able to use that constant. You will just use the constant directly, without having to use `require` or anything else.

But if you want to be squeaky clean with your code, `ActiveSupport` provides you with a *different* method that you can use to load these files: `require_dependency`.

```
require_dependency 'test_service'

class IndexController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

Although it's confusing that you would attempt to be squeaky clean and explicitly load the file containing `TestService` but not explicitly load the file containing `ApplicationController`....

You do not need to change the `autoload_paths` config.

---

## Update 1

In order to let Rails find and load your constants (classes and modules), you need to do the following:

You must be sure that every reloadable constant in your application is in a file with the right filename. The file must always be in some subdirectory of `app`, such as `app/models` or `app/services` or any other subdirectory. If the constant is named `TestService`, the filename must end with `test_service.rb`.

The algorithm is: `"TestService".underscore + ".rb" #=> "test_service.rb"`.

```
filename_glob = "app/*/" + the_constant.to_s.underscore + ".rb"
```

So if the constant is `TestService`, then the glob is `app/*/test_service.rb`. So sticking the constant in `app/services/test_service.rb` will work, as will `app/models/test_service.rb`, although the latter is bad form. If the constant were `SomeModule::SomeOtherModule::SomeClass`, you would need to put the file in `app/*/some_module/some_other_module/some_class.rb`.

Comment: Adding require_dependency ... seems to work. However, if I remove it, changes to TestService are not loaded.

Comment: Undo the change to the `autoload_paths` config. Don't set that config at all.

Comment: I already deleted that. Get this error, if I don't have require or require_dependency in the controller. uninitialized constant IndexController::TestService

Comment: In summary, remove `require`, change filename to `snake_case`.

Answer (score 0):

You say that your file is in `app/server`, but you are autoloading `app/service`. Which is correct?

Rename your file to `app/service/test_service.rb` and the autoloader should work. Rails looks for snake_cased filenames in your autoload paths. You don't need the manual `require` either, once you have the autoloading behavior correct.